# Rails ActiveRecord Includes with Inner Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

When using `includes` on an ActiveRecord model, is there a better way to specify an inner join then:

```
User.includes(:address).joins(:address)
```

It seems like there should be a more beautiful way to specify when you want an inner join and an includes?

Comment: Why do you need to call both? You shouldn't need includes and joins, should you? Do you want only records that have an address? `joins` should give you that. Do you want all the users even if there isn't an address association? `includes` should give you those.

Comment: Also, if you need to be more specific about joins, you can give a chunk of SQL. But you don't need that for just an `INNER JOIN` which is the natural output of `joins`. Here's the docs on the subject: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins

Comment: The :includes will preload or eager load the association, but a :joins won't. So if you want to load the association and specify an inner join, that is the best solution I've come up with -- just not very beautiful code.

Answer (score 10):

As Tom Rossi explained in the comment section of your question.

- If you want to join the address table with inner join association you
  should use join()
- If you want to preload the data you should use
  include() or eager_load(). I Personally prefer eager_load() function,
  because it guaranties that left join is going to be use. includes()
  may decide to use separate queries instead of left join association
- If you want to use inner join and preload the data you just combine
  the two approaches as it is in you case

Comment: As I said in the question, it works, it just isn't very beautiful.